# OpenID Connect, oAuth2 - Where to start?

Tags: oauth-2.0, api-design, openid-connect

I am not sure which approach I should be taking in our implementation and need some guidance.

I have a REST API (api.mysite.com) built in the Yii2 Framework (PHP) that accesses data from mysite.com (database). On mysite.com our users will be able to create Connected Apps that will provision a client id + secret - granting access to their account (full scope?).

Based on my research, the next step seems to be setting up something to actually provide the bearer tokens to be passed to the api - I have been leaning towards oAuth2, but then I read that oAuth2 does not provide authentication. Based on this I think I need OpenID Connect in order to also provide user tokens because my API needs to restrict data based on the user context.

In this approach, it is my understanding that I need to have an Authentication Server - so a few questions:

- Is there software I can install to act as an OpenID Connect/oAuth2 authentication server?
- Are there specific Amazon Web Services that will act as an OpenID Connect/oAuth2 Authentication Server?
- I am assuming the flow will be: App makes a request to the auth server with client id + secret and receives an access token. Access token can be used to make API calls. Where are these tokens stored (I am assuming a database specific to the service/software I am using?)
- When making API calls would I pass a bearer token AND a user token?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

your understanding is not very far from reality.
Imagine you have two servers one for Authentication, this one is responsible for generating the tokens based on a Authorization Basic and base64 encoded CLientID / ClientSecret combo. This is application authentication basically. If you want to add user data as well, simply pass username / password in the post body, authenticate on the server side and then add some more data to the tokens, like the usernames, claims, roles, etc

You can control what you put in these tokens, if you use something like JWT ( Json Web Tokens ) then they are simply json bits of data.

then you have a Resource server, you hit it with a Authorization Bearer and the token you obtained from the Authorization one.

Initially the tokens are not stored anywhere, they are issued for a period of time you control. You can however do something else and store them in a db if you really want to. The expiration is much safer though, even if someone gets their hands on them they won't be available for long! In my case I used 30 minutes for token validity.

Now, you haven't specified what languages/frameworks you are looking into. If you use something like dot net then look into IdentityServer, version 4 is for Dot net core, 3 for anything below.

I also have a pretty long article on this subject if you are interested:

https://eidand.com/2015/03/28/authorization-system-with-owin-web-api-json-web-tokens/

Hopefully all this clarifies some of the questions you have.

-- Added to answer a question in comments.

The tokens contain all the information they need to be authenticated by the resource server correctly, you don't need to store them in a database for that. As I already said, you can store them but in my mind this makes them less secure. Don't forget you control what goes into a token so you can add usernames if that's what you need.

Imagine this scenario, you want to authenticate the application and the user in the same call to the Authorization Server. Do the OAuth2 in the standard way, which means authenticate the application first based on the client id / client secret. If that passes then next do the user authentication. Add the username or userid to the token you generate and any other bits of information you need. What this means that the resource server can safely assume that the username passed to it in the token has already been validated by the authentication server otherwise no token would have been generated in the the first place.

I prefer to keep these two separate myself, meaning let the AS (  Authorization Server) to deal with the application level security. Then on the RS (Resource Server) side you have an endpoint point like ValidateUser for example, which takes care of the user validation, after which you can do whatever you need. Pick whichever feels more appropriate for your project I'd say.

One final point, ALWAYS make sure  all your api calls ( both AS and RS are just apis really ) are made over HTTPS and never ever have any important information transmitted via a GET call which means the URL can be intercepted. Both Headers and POST body are encrypted and secure over HTTPS.

This should address both your questions, I believe.

Comment: I will definitely read your article. But i have another question - With regards to the token - I was always under the impression the token would be stored somewhere so that when I make a call to the API and pass the Bearer token it could look up the Application and/or Account the token is used for? Is this incorrect?

Comment: And one additional question: we are running under AWS so I can deploy an nginx server or apache etc. I just need to understand how to setup/run an Authorization Server that supports oAuth2.0 and whatever mechanism I can use to transfer user information (e.g. UserID or UserToken) etc

Comment: Hi Andrei - You are extremely helpful in this matter. I am starting to get a better grip of where I need to head. I think one thing that is still unclear to me is my 2nd comment above. What do I use as an Authorization Server? Are there SASS implementations of this where I can sign up for an account and have it generate tokens for me etc or will I be deploying some software on one of our machines in order to act as an authorization server?

Also, since the tokens are not stored anywhere - what prevents someone from faking a token? Is the token encrypted / decrypted using a shared key?